# What collar badge did the 36th Battery of the Canadian Field Artillery in WW1 wear?

Tags: world-war-one, uniform, canada

My Great-Grandfather fought with the 36th Battery CFA of the 9th Brigade during at least a portion of WW1. He was in three other units as well, I'm trying to collect the collar badges for each unit he was part of, but I'm having a heck of a time trying to find a collar badge for the 36th Battery. Did they have a collar badge? If so does anyone know where I can at least find a picture so I can see what it looks like?

(note: Not to be confused with the 36th *Battalion CEF* of WW1)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you asked the CWM for help?

Comment: @kimchilover Nope. I had to google what CWM was. Thanks for that, I'll look into it.